# Draggable And Margin:0 auto;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Theres an issue with jQuery UI sortable/draggable, where if the element being dragged is centered using `margin:0 auto`, the dragging begins on the left side of the container rather than the center where the element really is.

Heres a demo to show what I mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqWRvV. Simply drag the red square.

If you remove `margin:0 auto` from the '.drag' element, you will see that the dragging starts normally.

How can I fix this issue and have my element drag from where it really is when centering using `margin:0 auto`?

This seems to happen in Google Chrome.

`$("#c").sortable();`

```
`.drag {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}`
```

centering the element with CSS 'calc' fixes the issue, but my elements width can change dynamically. Also 'calc' isn't as well supported as 'margin'.

Wrapping the draggable in a container fixes the issue, but HTML changes isn't a solution I'm looking for.

**UPDATE:**
So this isn't a jQuery bug. It's a bug with google chrome. Apparently the wrong position is retrieved by chrome, and so jQuery starts the drag from where chrome tells it where the element is. I output the left position of the element in the console and you can see that it's 13px when it clearly isn't. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqWRvV. I'm wondering if this bug has been reported.

**SOLUTION**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyjeJP Thanks to Julien Grégoire
Note: This solution may need a way to refresh the helper position.

Comment: I am using FirefoxDeveloperEdition and I do not see the bug

Comment: I see it works on firefox. Meaning this is a Chrome issue, try it on Chrome and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome returns the position differently than Firefox, but you get proper coordinates using **offset**, which is what sortable uses. The problem is that on **mouseStart**, the margin are removed from the calculations, which probably makes sense when you have a margin set. But with auto margin it creates this problem.

You could add an option to ignore margins and modify **_mouseStart**. Like this:

```
$("#c").sortable({
  ignoreMargins: true
});

$.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStart = function(event, overrideHandle, noActivation) {
    ...
    if (!this.options.ignoreMargins) {

      this.offset = {
        top: this.offset.top - this.margins.top,
        left: this.offset.left - this.margins.left
      };
    }
    ...
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKzeMp

EDIT:

If you don't want to modify the plugin, you can work with **start** and **stop** event. One problem is that it's hard to check if margins have been set to auto, so you define them in your sortable call, which is not as flexible as it should be, or you find a way to check which margins are auto dynamically.

```
$("#c").sortable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    var marginsToSet = ui.item.data().sortableItem.margins;
    // You set the margins here, so they don't go back to 0 
    // once the item is put in absolute position
      ui.item.css('margin-left', marginsToSet.left);
      ui.item.css('margin-top', marginsToSet.top);

  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    // Then you need to set the margins back once you stop dragging.
    // Ideally this should be dynamic, but you have to be able
    // to check which margins are set to auto, which as you'll
    // see if you look for some answers on this site, 
    // doesn't look that simple.
    ui.item.css('margin', '20px auto');
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPrdYp

Comment: This may be the solution I'm looking for and it seems to be working for now. It looks like it's changing a lot of core jQuery stuff. Is this safe? what problems may this bring up?

Comment: I ran into an issue. If the element has margin-top, the same thing that's been fixed horizontally, now happens vertically. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZqbQv

Comment: As soon as your margin value isn't 0px when in absolute position it'll cause a problem. That's why I suggest to be able to switch it with an option, because it won't work in all cases. That being said there maybe other side effects, but normally with minimal testing you should be able to see if it works in real situation. As for safeness, you only add an option, which has no incidence, and skip one statement. But yeah, it's not ideal. You could always create another sortable from the original one with this change. Or try to replicate this behavior using start event.

Comment: about the margin-top issue, see previous comment, it's because you have a non 0 margin when in absolute position. There may be other ways to deal with this, but if you want to keep auto margins in there, you could use this same ignore margin solution, but add an axis option. It's a bit clumsy, but it's not an easy problem and in general the whole sortable plugin isn't that straightforward to begin with.

Comment: So I'm right back where I started. I don't know if this solution is ideal. How do you think fixing the issue with the start event might work?

Comment: see edit, it's one way, there are probably others. Not sure which is the best. I think modifying the plugin is more direct and clearer. After all it is a jquery issue, and the issue can be targeted to that line of code. So for me it's not a problem adjusting the jquery code itself to prevent this. But working with start event allows you to target only one instance at a time, so it may be safer.

Comment: The second method seems to be working just fine, although heres an improved version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyjeJP. Applying the margin changes to the helper is better since it doesn't actually effect the real sortable element, only the clone. also removing the margin styles on 'stop' isn't necessary. Honestly I can't believe it's this simple and didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am testing your Codepen and checked it in two different browser (Mozilla & Chrome).

I got something that what you are saying is for Chrome. But in Mozilla it's working fine.

And in chrome position left property value is different. Means in Mozilla it's left: 560px while dragging and in Chrome it's starting from left: 0;

That is the reason of dramatically showing dragging element from the left.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Update your jQuery to add the clone helper:

```
$("#c").sortable({
 helper: "clone"
});
```

And update your CSS to add position and overflow:

```
#c {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  border: solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXXdzd)**

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but its not what I'm looking for because I'll have to wrap my many elements in a container, and that container is what's being dragged. Not the red square itself. Although this may be a good solution for others stumbling across this post in the future

Answer (score 0):

well the workaround i came around is
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaaaaZ

use `calc` instead of auto in CSS

Comment: Calc doesn't seem to center the element automatically regardless of width. Also it doesn't have good browser compatibility. I'll have to keep looking

Comment: i have tested on chrome and firefox it works fine and calc will make element center if written in correct way i.e. `calc(100% - width of element/2)`

Comment: it supports almost all major browsers http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/func_calc.asp

Comment: In my situation elements wdith will change constantly and dynamically. So calc isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set center with CSS than another option is set center with JQuery.
Please check out Demo i updated in your code base on your feedback and requirement which you explained in this post and other's answer. [Demo](http://codepen.io/ankitkothari225/pen/VajxYr)

```
$("#c").sortable();

$(".drag").css("margin-left",($(document).width()/2)-125);
$(window).resize(function(){
   $(".drag").css("margin-left",($(document).width()/2)-125);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on Chrome `.sortable()`  doesn't properly calculate position of element when you use `margin: 0 auto` and just set `left` position as `0`. So i guess you should find other way to horizontally center you element.

---

One option is to use `text-align: center` on parent element and `display: inline-block` on child

```js
$("#c").sortable();
```

```css
#c {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  border: solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.drag {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="c">
  <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

Other one is to use [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and center child elements with `justify-content: center`

```js
$("#c").sortable();
```

```css
#c {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  border: solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drag {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="c">
  <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Text align method may be something ill look into, but I'll wait for a better option. The problem isn't with jquery. its with JavaScript getting the wrong position of the element.